# How to obtain display device characteristics in Android?

Tags: android, google-tv

Folks,

Our application is intended to run only for a specific model  of display monitor having a specific serial number. On Linux version of our app, we obtain this information via EDID.

We are now looking at porting the  code over to Android (Google TV).

Is there any API on Android NDK that would let us obtain display device characteristics such as its model and serial number?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Google TV devices don't have telephony hardware, you cannot use the TelephonyManager to get the device id.

You can get other device information using the following code:

```
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE="+android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL="+android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "android.os.Build.DEVICE="+android.os.Build.DEVICE);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "android.os.Build.MODEL="+android.os.Build.MODEL);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "android.os.Build.PRODUCT="+android.os.Build.PRODUCT);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER="+android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "android.os.Build.BRAND="+android.os.Build.BRAND);
```

For the Vizio Co-Star Google TV device you will get the following:

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE=3.2
android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL=U4.6.0-ota2
android.os.Build.DEVICE=VAP430
android.os.Build.MODEL=VAP430
android.os.Build.PRODUCT=StreamPlayer
android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER=VIZIO
android.os.Build.BRAND=Vizio
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. My need is to obtain the information for the attached display device (TV, Projector, etc.) to Co-Star, not Co-Star itself. As your answer is the closest to what I am looking for, I will go ahead and mark it as the solution for now. Regards, Peter.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump all the features using the following:

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(id.featurestextview);

    FeatureInfo features[] = getPackageManager()
            .getSystemAvailableFeatures();
    Log.d("Features", "getSystemAvailableFeatures() = " + features);

    text.append("Supported System Features on this device:\n\n");

    if (features != null) {
        for (FeatureInfo featureInfo : features) {
            if (featureInfo.name!= null) {
                text.append(featureInfo.name+"  (Flags: "+featureInfo.flags+") \n");
            } else {
                text.append(featureInfo+"\n");
            }
        }
    }

    long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    int memoryClass = ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();
    MemoryInfo memInfo = new MemoryInfo();
    ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryInfo(memInfo);


    text.append("\n\nMEMORY:\nMaxMemory "+maxMemory/1024+"KB / "+maxMemory/1024/1024+"MB");
    text.append(" (Memory Class: "+memoryClass+")");
    text.append("\n MemoryInfo: Avail="+ memInfo.availMem / 1024 +"KB   Threshold="+memInfo.threshold /1024 +"KB");
```

The android build properties for vendor etc will allow you to scope to a specific device. With respect to a serial number (eg. a cpu serial - is not available) we recommend you use the mac address.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will this give me information on the attached display device such as the TV or the projector? Regards, Peter

Comment: That kind of info is only available via HDMI CEC which is not supported fully in the tv market right now. You will not be able to find out the kind of device you are connected to via HDMI currently.